# 3D indicator function of a box with balls

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, piecewise

I want to define the indicator function of finite number of identical balls with given centers and diameter in a box in Wolfram Mathematica. The box has the dimensions $0 \leq x_1 \leq l$, $0 \leq x_2 \leq l$, $0 \leq x_3 \leq 1$, the diameter of a typical ball is $d$.

My try is as follows (for 1 ball):

`UnitStep[1/4 d^2 - (x1 - x01)^2 - (x2 - x02)^2 - (x3 - x03)^2]`

which seems to be logical. However, for `d = 0.1`, `x01 = 0.75`, `x02 = 0.5`, `x03 = 0.5`, `l = 5` and any `0 < x3 < 1`, this function results in
[image]

How to define the distribution of, e.g., 10 equidistant balls in the box, if `x03 = 0.5`? Any hint or suggestion is highly appreciated.

**Edit**

I also tried with `Piecewise`:

```
Piecewise[{{1, (x1 - 0.5)^2 + (x2 - 0.5)^2 <= 
    1/4 0.5^2}, {1, (x1 - 1.5)^2 + (x2 - 0.5)^2 <= 
    1/4 0.5^2}, {1, (x1 - 2.5)^2 + (x2 - 0.5)^2 <= 
    1/4 0.5^2}, {1, (x1 - 3.5)^2 + (x2 - 0.5)^2 <= 
    1/4 0.5^2}, {1, (x1 - 4.5)^2 + (x2 - 0.5)^2 <= 1/4 0.5^2}}, 0]
```

which plots
[image]

But I am not sure that this will provide the required result if I add `(x3-x03)^2` to the conditions at `Piecewise`.

Comment: Try with `RegionPlot3D` instead of `ContourPlot3D`, which I'm guessing is what you are using.

Comment: No, I use `Plot3D`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions: one with `ImplicitRegion` and `Show` that is somewhat slow, and one with `RegionPlot3D` as Dan suggested. (Since indicator function is requested, I guess second solution's part `Apply[Or, First /@ balls]` is of interest.)

```
d = 0.05;
cs = RandomReal[{0.1, 0.9}, {10, 3}];

balls = ImplicitRegion[
     Sqrt[(#[[1]] - x)^2 + (#[[2]] - y)^2 + (#[[3]] - z)^2] <= d, {x, y, z}] & /@ cs;

Show[Region /@ balls, Boxed -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot3D[
 Apply[Or, First /@ balls], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotPoints -> 40]
```

[image]

Comment: Since I need to integrate the requested indicator function with respect to `x3`, I need it to be expressed in terms of `Piecewise`, `UnitStep`, `HeavisideTheta`, etc. I tried to integrate `Apply[...]`, and got integral of inequalities with `||`.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan You can use `Boole[Apply[Or, First /@ balls]]` in `NIntegrate` and `Integrate`. (Also, in your question you did not say anything about integration...)

Comment: Theoretically, `UnitStep[0.25 d^2 - x1^2 - x2^2 - x3^2]` characterizes a ball  of diameter `d` centered at `[0, 0, 0]`. Why it is not giving what it sopposed to give?

Comment: `Plot3D` and `ContourPlot3D` I guess are looking for 2 dimensional surfaces and not getting the depth part. That's just a guess though. As noted, `Boole` is just fine for integration. Likewise `ImplicitRegion` I believe.

Comment: Could you also help me to handle a specific case, when we have 50 (non-overlapping) balls with equidistant centers and `x03 = 0.5` is fixed? How then `cs` looks like?

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan Did you figure out the answer of your 50 balls question? The variable `cs` just holds the centers of the balls.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Unfortunately, not. In my case, `cs = {x01[n], x02[m], x03}`, where `x01[n_] := 2n*d`, `x02[m_] := 2m*d` and `x03 = 0.5`. But I am not sure how to define this correctly.

Comment: @AsaturKhurshudyan Try this: `Block[{x01, x02, x03 = 0.5, d = 0.03},
 x01[n_] := 2 n*d; x02[m_] := 2 m*d;
 Table[{x01[n], x02[n], x03}, {n, 1, 50}]
 ]`

Comment: Plots perfectly, however integrating is too slow.